# export canvas data to json

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, export

Hay guys, i've made a simple drawing application using the canvas tag. However i would like to export the data to JSON so it can be saved.

How does one go about this?

Comment: I don't think there is any particular JSON format corresponding to what you draw on the canvas.

Comment: Is there anyway i can export the canvas data, with the option to be able to import it again at a later date.

Comment: Of course you can but as far as I know there is no particular format for doing that. You probably need to invent your own format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is the [toDataUrl(type)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) method. It will return a data: URI – a plain string which you can easily put in a JSON structure or do what you want with. Example:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width=8;
canvas.height=8;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
/* draw on ctx */
alert(canvas.toDataURL());
/* result: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAADUlEQVR42mNgGAUgAAABCAABXbcZDQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== */
```

Tested in Opera 10.0. You can also try .toDataURL("image/jpeg")

Comment: Android 2.x doesn't seem to have support for toDataURL: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901